# Chart Js source file typeerror

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In Chart.js source file, there is an error on line ten, like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined
at new e (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js:10:74)
at history (file:///Users/zhenglong/Desktop/Programming/Projects/Proto%20Eclipse/Proto%20Eclipse%20Application/Admin/Workspace/Javascript/command.js:359:14)
at main (file:///Users/zhenglong/Desktop/Programming/Projects/Proto%20Eclipse/Proto%20Eclipse%20Application/Admin/Workspace/Javascript/command.js:144:4)
at HTMLInputElement.fir.onkeydown (file:///Users/zhenglong/Desktop/Programming/Projects/Proto%20Eclipse/Proto%20Eclipse%20Application/Admin/Workspace/admin.html:35:10)
```

any idea on how i solve it? it's on the source file

Comment: 1. What code are you using to create your chart? 2. Chart.js 1.0.2 is very old, you should use the latest unless this is a legacy app that is not easily upgraded.

Comment: @jeffcarey 1.0.2 is the only thing i found .-. can you gimme the new cdn?

Comment: One example: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js/2.4.0

Comment: @jeffcarey it won't load though

Comment: It loads for me. The API for creating a new chart is slightly different than before. Try looking at http://www.chartjs.org/docs/ for examples.